# Equivariant sheaves basics reference

Tags: equivariant, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for basic facts about 
actions of linear algebraic groups and their Lie-algebras on $\mathcal O_X$-modules.

For example I could not find a reference the following:

Let $G$ be a connected, complex linear algebraic group. Then 
an $\mathcal O_X$-linear map between two $G$-equivariant $\mathcal O_X$-modules commutes with the group actions iff it commutes with the Lie-algebra actions.

Comment: Chapter 5, section 1 of Chriss and Ginzburg contains many nice facts about $G$-equivariant $\mathcal{O}$-modules.  However, they do not discuss Lie algebra actions at all.